# Id is too long when it access through session in jsp.

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, session, servlets

I access the `customer id` and save it in order table as `foriegn key` against his current order record is save successfully but `customer id` is too long I get it as ( `String user= session.getId();`) but in database is look like as(`489B37FC975A6B831EAA685124DC8A38`) I have much confusion how to solve it?
Thanks

Comment: what is the column size of your database?

Comment: i set the size of foriegn key is 100

Answer (score 1):

Session `id` is some temporary value that is not associated with persistent information.  When the customer will return later, once session has expired, there will be new value.

> String getId()
>
> Returns a string containing the unique identifier assigned to this session. 
>   The identifier is assigned by the servlet container and is implementation 
>   dependent.

You should create `Customer` object, persist it and save its `id` into session when user logs in. This is the correct way.

Comment: please u can share any link or some code that how to do i am new in java thanks

Comment: Take a look at my OAuthLogin project, there is web module with servlets and ejb module with JPA (db layer): https://github.com/literakl/OAuthLogin. See User.java for example.